# Black display - MacBook Pro 13" Function Keys 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, display

This happened out of the blue. Screen went black and I haven’t been able to get it to come back on.

Prerequisites:
 • No liquid damage
 • No drops/impacts recently
 • Nothing out of the norm leading up to the issue
 • Capslock key lights up
 • Charging sound when cable is plugged in
 • Trackpad clicks
 • No keyboard backlight
 • No startup chime

What I’ve tried:
 • SMC Reset
 • PRAM Reset
 • Removed bottom cover and reseated battery connectors and other connectors that were easily removed. Nothing looked out of the norm.
 • Booted laptop without battery connected using AC adapter

What I haven’t tried:
 • Plugging into my own external display.

Apple’s brief diagnosis:
 • Nothing shows on external display
 • Likely logic board
 • $500 to replace logic board

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. A $500 repair is not in the budget right now. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest hooking up an external monitor to see if the logic board still works.  It could be the display itself or the logic board.  Without putting hands on, there’s no reason to dispute Apple’s diagnosis.  However, you may wish to get a second opinion and I would recommend [Rossman Group](https://rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC. I’m not affiliated other than being a satisfied customer.

Comment: Picked up a USB-C to HDMI adapter and plugged in a monitor. Monitor simply showed a gray screen with the mouse pointer. I could tell the display was being extended and not mirrored, so I played around with some key combinations to try and mirror it and stumbled upon voice over. I was able to navigate through the startup menu with voice over and login. When logging in it made a couple strange beeps, almost like a BIOS would on a PC. I can see the internal display is detected, and the keyboard backlight turned on now as well. Not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: This means that the graphic subsystem on the logic board still works.  It could still be the logic board itself - the connector or a backlight fuse - or it could be the display.  Check out a 3rd party repair company like Rossman